# Is it possible to have differently colored lines in multiline text box?

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, textbox

Is it possible to have differently colored lines in multiline text box?

I'm adding data to the text box and I want to clarify for the user different types of text by color.

How to do this if it's possible?

Comment: Which UI framework are you using (Winforms, WPF, Web)?

Comment: @M.Babcock, ah! I forgot to add the tag. It's winforms.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this if you use a `RichTextBox` control. See the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx) (particularly look at the Remarks and Examples sections).  The standard TextBox does not offer this capability.

Answer (score 3):

The standard Winforms textbox does not have this ability (and adding it would be troublesome).

You could look at using the [`System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx) as an alternative for this or one of the many commercial alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

So depending on how you want the output, there's an browser/html control (basically a box), that you can pass a URL or a string of HTML, depending on what you're doing, you might want to use the RickTextBox - which has formatting commands - you could use regular expressions, or the offset of the text and then use a "set color" command on the text box with an IF structure.

Answer (score 1):

I find a way without using the RichTextBox

```
        WrapPanel panel = new WrapPanel();
        foreach (....)
        {

            TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
            if(.....)
                tb.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
            else
            {
                tb.Foreground = Brushes.LemonChiffon;
            panel.Children.Add(tb);
         }
```

and finally

```
                stackPanel.Children.Add(panel);
                
            }
            scrollViewer.Content = stackPanel;
            scrollViewer.CanContentScroll = true;
            window.Content = scrollViewer;
            window.Show();
```

Its not necessary to ust the Scrollviewer. But well in my App i needed it.
However like this its possible to generate Multicolor text...and an extra for free. Each part of the text can easiely have a ToolTip