# Change the color of different lines in a textbox in codebehind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, code-behind

I need to have have diffrent lines in different colors for a textbox.

I donot want to use a rictextbox.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtMessage" runat="server" Width="550" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="242px" />
```

Is there any way to use some html to achieve this?

I have tried this but it doesnot work:

```
Txtmsg2.Text = "<span style='color: red;'>ENFIELD ONLY:</span>" & Chr(13)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have differently colored lines in multiline text box?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957981/is-it-possible-to-have-differently-colored-lines-in-multiline-text-box)

Comment: (Note that the question I linked is for Winforms, not web forms, but I believe the answer is the same.)

Comment: why not use <input> control. and then format it. Just make sure you put runat="server" in it.

Comment: The reason i wanted an ordinary textbox to do this is because I have a lot of code which will need changing..So I see that the ordinary textbox can never do it which is bad ..:-(

Comment: Thank you for all your help tho.I might try telerik rad editor or freetextbox

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible within a text area, you'll need to use a rich text box (which I see you don't want to use) or a WYSIWYG editor such as [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.com).

Comment: The reason i wanted an ordinary textbox to do this is because I have a lot of code which will need changing.

Comment: Thank you for your help.Im planning to use a telrik editor